# Is there a build in Observable that fires next after the previous in the chain has completed?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I am looking for some pre-built functionality that does something like this:

```js
const Rx = require('rxjs');
const proto = Rx.Observable.prototype;

proto.whenCompleted = function () {

    const source = this;

    return Rx.Observable.create(sub => {

        const ret = [];
        return source.subscribe(
            function (v) {
                ret.push(v);
            },
            function (e) {
                sub.error(e);
            },
            function () {
                sub.next(ret);
            }
        )

    });

};
```

is there an RxJS observable method that can do that?

Comment: Sounds like some use of one of the `concat*` operators should do what you need. Have you tried to use any of those?

Comment: You can `.concat(...)` to subscribe after the previous has completed, or you can use `.toArray()` to gather all items and return them inside the array when Observable completed. Is this what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concat` allows you to merge streams "one after another".

E.g.: in the case below, the stream will first emit 1, 2, 3 and only after that will send the form changes.

```js
from([1, 2, 3])
.pipe( 
  concat(
    myForm.get('age').valueChanges
  ) 
)
```